# Is Image Stabilization better in the lens or the body?

Tags: lens, image-stabilization, lens-design, body

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between in-lens image stabilizing and in-sensor image stabilizing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-is-the-difference-between-in-lens-image-stabilizing-and-in-sensor-image-sta)

Some DSLR manufacturers have image stabilization (IS) in the body of their cameras, others sell (some) lenses with IS. Are there particular advantages of one over the other?

(Apart from only having to pay for it once when it is in the body).