# Sony a6300 image stabilization

Tags: mirrorless

I am trying to make a move from point and shoot (I own nikon p510) to interchangeable lenses. I have zoomed into

[Sony Alpha A6300 16-50mm F3.5-5.6 OSS PZ + 55-210mm F4.5-6.3 OSS](https://www.rhinocamera.se/product.aspx?ProductID=21835)
and
[Fujifilm X-T20](https://www.dpreview.com/news/2109589229/feisty-upstart-hands-on-with-the-fujifilm-x-t20)

which got fairly good review and matches my pocket.
But since I am new in this field, I am still lost. 
I have a very shaky hand, so some type of image stabilization is necessary. But, in this type of camera, there is mostly in lens stabilization. Can you guys please help me a bit with commenting how good this will be for mostly indoor/outdoor portrait and landscape shots?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between in-lens image stabilizing and sensor-based image stabilizing?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-is-the-difference-between-in-lens-image-stabilizing-and-sensor-based-image/15425)

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I agree that there are a bunch of similar questions; and mine is bit blurry, but here I tried not to ask a generic question, that may tend to a brand war, but if I will get some type of image stabilization from this two model. Also, if it is possible to pick up an easy winner between these two.

Comment: Can you clarify your use case a bit more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between in-lens image stabilizing and sensor-based image stabilizing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-is-the-difference-between-in-lens-image-stabilizing-and-sensor-based-image)

Answer (score 2):

Neither the Sony A6300 nor the Fujfilm X-T20 have in-body image stabilization.

You have linked to a Sony bundle which includes two lenses with the "OSS" designation — these *do* include image-stabilization. You can read more about the advantages and disadvantages of each approach at [What is the difference between in-lens image stabilizing and sensor-based image stabilizing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-is-the-difference-between-in-lens-image-stabilizing-and-sensor-based-image/15425)

Your link to the Fujifilm camera is just to a review of the body, with no lenses mentioned, but the roughly-equivalent zoom lenses in the [Fujfilm lineup](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/xf_lens/roadmap/) are all "OIS" lenses — Fujifilm's term for in-lens stabilization.

In short, the availability of image stabilization for this particular comparison isn't a factor. In deciding between the systems, you might want to focus more on particular lenses and applications. For example, Fujifilm does not currently offer image stabilization on any of its X-mount prime lenses (although an 80mm macro with OIS is planned), while Sony offers a number of [options](https://www.sony.net/Products/di/en-us/products/lenses/lineup/#body/a6300/) like a 35mm f/1.8 with OSS. But, whether that matters depends a lot on you.