# Budget Nikon setup - future problems due to AF-S vs AF?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the lack of AF Motor on the Nikon D5100 an important factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17093/is-the-lack-of-af-motor-on-the-nikon-d5100-an-important-factor)

I am just starting up as an amateur photographer to venture into DSLRs. Being on a tight budget, I am currently considering Nikon D5100 and Canon 600D, with preference towards Nikon due to its better image quality, focus system and sensor quality.

Problem is that a lens for above Canon such as *Sigma 70-300mm F/4-5.6 DG Macro (for Canon AF Digital SLR) Lens (Macro Lens)* would autofocus, but *Sigma 70-300mm F/4-5.6 DG Macro (for Nikon Digital SLR) Lens (Macro Lens)* for Nikon in the above body would not focus as D5100 does not have focus motor in built. Both these lenses are for about $170 at the moment.
I have few questions here:

1. If I do buy the above Nikon lens, will it also work in future on
   Nikon D7000?
2. In case of D7000, will this lens start auto-focusing
   automatically?
3. What do I loose in future on say, D7000 by using
   this lens instead of an AF-S lens for this configuration? (Which is
   double the cost of this lens)