# What is difference between autofocus and built-in autofoucs motor?

Tags: nikon

While reading reviews on the internet I found that most Nikon dslrs do not have built in auto focus motor. For example D3200 do not have auto-focus motor. When I read the sepecs of `D3200` in `nikon` and other websites I found that they have excellent auto focus system.
This pushed me in great confusion. Can you please help me understanding this issu?

Comment: Also: [Is the lack of AF Motor on the Nikon D5100 an important factor?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17093/is-the-lack-of-af-motor-on-the-nikon-d5100-an-important-factor)

Answer (score 0):

Autofocus is the system that focuses the lens automatically, after half-pressing the shutter or focus button. The autofocus system consists of sensors, software AND the autofocus motor. The autofocus motor is not in every nikon lens available.

In your example, somebody wanted to say that a lens (with autofocus motor, af-s lenses for example) combined with the camera delivers good autofocus results.

Comment: It means the above model do not capable of autofocusing?

Answer (score 0):

A quick short answer: bodies without a motor rely on a motor in the lens. All current Canon lenses work this way, as do all *new* Nikon lenses. See the questions I marked as duplicates above for more.