# Options for a wide angle lens for Nikon D5000?

Tags: lens, nikon, wide-angle, ultra-wide, nikon-d5000

I'm not sure if all Nikon lenses have identical connectors across all models (amateur here), so I'm sorry if it's a silly question.

I have a D5000 and I'm looking to do more night time photography and also general scenery, so I'm thinking a wide would be a good investment. What suggestions do you have, and which filters would make sense with it? (I already have an adjustable ND filter).

Comment: Oh its possible, but I am amateur and have yet to learn about sensors. A little research shows that my camera is indeed DX and APS-C format. I guess my question was more about the body and attachment? But as user below pointed out, all Nikons have same F mount. I'm not sure if the question is different enough to be considered duplicate, but I did learn things from the two answers below that weren't on the other thread. Also the other thread was useful to me too. Go figure.

Comment: Also, and forgive me if this sounds stupid, but some Nikon cameras can motor the lens and some can't right? I think mine can't, so the autofocus won't work. So I guess the actual model of the camera would be relevant as a separation from the other thread which was non-specific?

Comment: @Steven  On the focus motor issue, see [Is the lack of AF Motor on the Nikon D5100 an important factor?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17093/is-the-lack-of-af-motor-on-the-nikon-d5100-an-important-factor)

Comment: @mattdm Oh thanks, so basically I have the wrong body! O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a D5300 and I recently bought a 20mm f/1.8 (http://www.nikon.com.au/en_AU/product/nikkor-lenses/fx-format/single-focal-length/wide-angle/af-s-nikkor-20mm-f-1-8g-ed) and it's honestly been my best purchase thus far. I forked out for it because I plan to upgrade to a FX body sometime in the near future, but if you want a really good reliable wide lens, I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: This is looking like a good option from what I've read

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Nikon user but if you are open to third party lenses I can recommend Tokina 11-20 f/2.8. I have a 11-16 f/2.8 (the predecessor of 11-20) and use it on my Canon (Tokina makes it for both Nikon and Canon). Gives me fantastic results and quite nicely built.

Sample images:

https://500px.com/photo/106655005/quiraing-isle-of-skye-by-pranet-patra?ctx_page=1&from=user&user_id=11072417

https://500px.com/photo/125083343/liverpool-city-centre-by-pranet-patra

Thanks,
Pranet.

Answer (score 0):

All Nikon cameras since the old times use the same F mount. So any f-mount lens will work on your camera.

However, only those with an integrated AF motor will be able to autofocus on a d5x00, and many old lenses won't be able to "tell" their aperture to the camera. So you'll have to use them in manual exposure, manual focus mode.

For night time photography, you'll have an advantage with a fast lens, that is with a large maximum aperture.  If you want a zoom, a 18-55 or 17-55 zoom with constant aperture of f/2.8 will give you versatility, or a wide prime like a 24 or less will likely be faster.

The nd filter won't help you in night photography since you'll need all the light that you can get. Actually, filters in general shouldn't be that useful for night photography. An exception could be a gradual nd filter to darken the foreground if there are any lights. The nd and circular polarizer can be used in landscapes though.

Comment: You think this will do the job? http://www.digidirect.com.au/camera_lenses/tokina/tokina_at-x_11-20mm_f28_pro_dx_lens_nikon_mount_1120prodxnik
The motor type says "Screw drive from camera". Does that mean it won't work with the D5000?

Comment: @Steven You can take pictures with it but you will need to manually focus to do so.

Comment: Actually from other sources I've seen that it has an internal autofocus motor, so you should be fine. But I believe you should pair it with a longer lens, also the kit 18-55 would do